# Group(Non-abelian) Multiplication Table

Tags: group-theory

> Given ***Group(Non-abelian) Multiplication Table***.
>    Find $ca,bb\text{ and }df$.

$$\begin{array}{ l | c  r  r  r  r  r }
 * & e & a & b & c & d &f \\
\hline
  e & e & a & b & c & d & f \\
  a & a & b & e & d \\
b&b\\
c&c&&&e&&a\\
d&d\\
f&f\\
\end{array}$$

---

**My question:**

> Is there an algorithm for filling up the empty cells? if there isnt, what is then the best approach?

Comment: Hint: Each row and each column must contain each of $a,b,c,d,e,f$ exactly once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may not be enough information to fill in the whole table, but there’s enough to answer the question. For instance, $ca=c(cf)=(cc)f=ef=f$. Note that $bb=(aa)b$ and $df=(ac)f$; can you take it from there?

Comment: I suspect there is enough information to fill in the whole table (though of course as you show there is no need to do so). From $ca=f$ and $ac=d$ we know it's not abelian, so it must be $S_3$. $a,b$ have order 3, $c,d,f$ must be transpositions, and so on.

Comment: @Gerry: True; I wasn’t thinking about the fact that it has to be $S_3$. I’m too lazy at the moment to try, so I’ll just change the wording slightly.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I came up with this: 
$$\begin{array}{ l | c  r  r  r  r  r }
 * & e & a & b & c & d &f \\
\hline
  e & e & a & b & c & d & f \\
  a & a & b & e & d&f&c \\
b&b&e&a&f&c&d\\
c&c&f&d&e&b&a\\
d&d&c&f&a&e&b\\
f&f&d&c&b&a&e\\
\end{array}$$ is this correct?

Comment: @JL90: I didn’t check every single entry, but I checked enough to be pretty sure that it is, yes.